# c# foreach loop updating all objects in collection

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, foreach

Looping over a collection of *downloadedCase* objects. The aim is to update a sorteddictionary (*CSVFullColumnList*) that exists as a property on each *downloadedCase* object.

Code as follows:

```
    private void generateCSVRows()
    {
        foreach (NewCase downloadedCase in downloadedCases)
        {
            downloadedCase.CSVFullColumnList = this.columnsWithNoValuesFinal;
        }
        string columnNameLower;
        foreach (NewCase downloadedCase in downloadedCases)
        {
            List<string> keys = new List<string>(columnsWithNoValues.Keys);
            foreach (string columnName in keys)
            {
                columnNameLower = columnName.ToLower();
                if (downloadedCase.CSVDataList.ContainsKey(columnNameLower))
                {
                    downloadedCase.CSVFullColumnList[columnNameLower] = downloadedCase.CSVDataList[columnNameLower];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

However when the code reaches the assignment inside the if statement, the assignment gets done against all *downloadedCase* objects. For example, on the first iteration, the third object in the collection also gets updated. Additionally, *columnsWithNoValuesFinal* also gets updated even though nothing is being assigned to it in the assignment statement.

[image: Unwanted Assignment]

Can somebody explain to me why this is happening?

Comment: You're most likely referencing the same object on them all, which means that you only ever have 1 object in play. You most likely want to clone the `columnsWithNoValuesFinal` that you assign to each downloaded case, in the first loop, to ensure each case has its own copy that can be modified separately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using objects, these are called "reference types", which means that you have two pieces in play:

- The object itself
- One or more references to the object

In this case you have 1 object, originally being referenced by the `columnsWithNoValuesFinal` field / variable.

Then you assign this **reference** to the `CSVFullColumnList` property of each downloaded case. You're making copies of the *reference*, but **not** the *object*.

So you end up with 1 object and many references.

You should probably make a copy / clone of this object inside the first loop, and assign the copies to each downloaded case, this will make all the objects distinct and separate, changing one will not change the others.

But now, you're just changing the one object you have, which makes it look like you change "them all".